# How to query an array in an array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am pretty new to mongodb, and I am not able to query in my mongo collection.

**Structure :**

```
"chapterId":1,
"videos" : [ 
        {
            "videoId" : "1",
            "videoName" : "about",
            "duration" : "12:36",
            "tags":["business", "design"]
        }, 
        {
            "videoId" : "2",
            "videoName" : "course",
            "duration" : "04:00",
            "tags":["technology", "design"]
        }
]
```

I need to select all videos with the tag "business" in chapterId 1.

Can this be done without changing the structure of my collection ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use aggregation so below query will help you

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
          {"$unwind":"$videos"},
          {"$match":{"chapterId":1,"videos.tags":"business"}}
          )
```